# Unable to Test AWS DMS End points in CLoud fromation template

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I am trying to build up a CloudFormation template to automate the migration process from on-premises to AWS Cloud. I have created all the required resources in Database Migration Service (DMS) including the Replication Instance, Endpoints and Tasks through CloudFormation itself.

Now, in order to go further, I need to test the Endpoints from the Replication Instance. This should be done in an automated way. Is it possible to achieve this task in a CloudFormation template?

Answer (score 0):

The Database Migration Service (DMS) exposes a service API called `TestConnection`. You can use the `TestConnection` API to validate connectivity to the endpoints that you've configured.

In order for the endpoint connectivity testing to succeed however, the DMS Replication Instance must be fully operational, [according to the service documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_RDSOracle2Aurora.Steps.CreateSourceTargetEndpoints.html).

> However, you can only test connectivity after the replication instance has been created, because the replication instance is used in the connection.

You could call the DMS `TestConnection` API from an AWS Lambda function. AWS Lambda has the AWS SDK built-in, so you can simply embed your Lambda code directly into the CloudFormation template. You don't need to worry about building a ZIP archive that includes the AWS SDK, unless you want to add other dependencies to your Lambda function.

[Database Migration Service | API Reference | TestConnection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/APIReference/API_TestConnection.html)

[Boto3 | AWS Python SDK | Database Migration Service | test_connection() method](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dms.html#DatabaseMigrationService.Client.test_connection)

Comment: If you have an sample JSON code which can complete this requirement please kindly forward it.